# Can I use Xcode 7 to build, release and deploy iOS 8 app to the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on Xcode 6 and now upgrading to Xcode 7.

Would I be able to build iOS 8 iPhone app using Xcode 7? Or do I have to use Xcode 6? Are there any restriction or compatibility issues that I should be aware of? Will I be able to deploy this build or release it to the App Store?

Comment: What do you mean by an "iOS 8" app? Any app with a "Deployment Target" of iOS 8 or earlier can run on a device with iOS 8. Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just change the deployment target of your app to 8.0:

[image: xcode]

There are no restrictions or compatibility issues, other than not being able to use any iOS 9 APIs in your app should you chose to target a lower SDK level.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Deployment Target to 8.0 in Target->General->Deployment Info. Xcode 7 will allow you to take advantage of many new features and still target iOS8 bearing devices.